# how to calculate the right resolution for an image overlay in openlayers

Tags: image, openlayers, resolution

I have an image I use as overlay in a vector layer in my openlayer web application. The idea is the same as showed in this [example](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL27/examples/ExternalGraphicOverlay/ExternalGraphicOverlay.asp)

What I do not understand is how to set a valid resolution to my image so that every time the user changes the zoom of the map, the image width and height is adjusted to cover its real geographical area.

In the example above some images are used and placed at some specific locations using a specific and hard-coded resolution factor.

Assume I have an image 400x400 pixel which represents an area of 400x400 kilometers, I need to recalculate the width and height of my image every time the zoom factor changes using a formula like this:

```
imageWidth = imageWidthInPixel * theResolution / map.getResolution(); 
imageHeight = imageHeightInPixel * theResolution / map.getResolution();
```

where 'theResolution' is the value I need to calculate some way I don't know. I guess this is a value that depends on the area expressed in kilometers or meters the image covers, but I am not able to find out a relation that has a sense. As explained above, in the example I reported, these values are hard-coded and depends on the image but there is no way to understand how these values are calculated.

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the projection of your image, it would be easiest to simply define the image as a layer defined in OpenLayers with the appropriate projection.  At that point, OpenLayers will handle the zooming and panning for you.